# My query keeps looping infinitely ! how to stop it?

Tags: php, wp-query, functions, loop

in my plugin I need to retrieve posts published by admins to display them in the back-end under posts so .. i fetch the admins ids through get_users and it's fine but whenever i try to build a query and pass these ids as author ids to get what these authors' posts my query keeps looping infinitely , here's the function :

```
function get_posts_by_admin_role() 
 {
   if(is_admin() && !is_front_page() && !is_singular() && !is_archive()) {

            $args =array(
                   'role'         => 'administrator'
                     'orderby'      => 'post_count',
                      'order'        => 'ASC',
                      'count_total'  => false
                         );
$Admins = get_users( $args );
// Array of WP_User objects.
foreach ( $Admins as $post_author )
 {
   $admin_ids= $post_author -> ID;
    echo $post_author -> display_name."<br/>";
     /*to see results not only get out of memory or time limit exceeded*/
    echo $post_author -> ID;
  }

$args2 = array( 'author__in' => $admin_ids );
$myposts = new WP_Query( $args2);
```

and it doesn't change the fact that it loops infinitely even if i put this :

```
if ($myposts -> have_posts())
        {
while ($myposts -> have_posts() ) 
       {
    $myposts -> the_post(); 

    echo $post->ID, '<br />';

        } // end while
            } // end if
else
 { 
echo "no posts";
 }

     }
 }
```

Is my query causing the problem ?cause I've tried a few  but they always loop infinitely and I try to keep it simple ..please help 
So I tried a new function that retrieves post ids of posts published by admins only problem is i cant get posts to show in the table in posts ..how can i do that ? here's the function

```
function get_posts_by_author_role($role) {
global $wpdb;
return $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT p.* FROM {$wpdb->posts} p, {$wpdb-    >usermeta} u"
                            ." WHERE    p.post_type     = 'post'"
                            ." AND      p.post_status   = 'publish'"
                            ." AND      u.user_id       = p.`post_author`"
                            ." AND      u.meta_key      = 'wp_capabilities'"
                            ." AND      u.meta_value    LIKE '%\"{$role}\"%'" );
}
```

I call it in this function:

```
function filter_posts_list($query)
 {
     if(is_admin() && !is_front_page() && !is_singular() && !is_archive()) 
     {
      $myposts = get_posts_by_admin_role('administrator');
         $post_id=array();
        foreach($myposts as $post)
        {
         //echo $post->post_title, '<br />'; 
           $post_id[]= $post->ID;
            echo $post->ID, '<br />';
        }


   if ( !$query->is_main_query() )
        return; 

   $query->set('post__in' ,array($post_id)); 
   // $query = new WP_Query( 'post__in' ,array($post_id) );
    //return $query;
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'filter_posts_list');
```

the $query->set shows no posts ! as for new WP_Query it shows all posts ..admin or not ! what am I missing?

Comment: Your code is difficult to read, can you indent it correctly?

Comment: try not to use `$posts` for your query, as this is also used in core functions...

Comment: is this better ?

Answer (score 0):

Like Tom commented, your code is hard to read. You can look at the code snippet below as a suggestion based on what your code.

```
function get_posts_by_admin_role( ) {
    if ( is_admin() && !is_front_page() && !is_singular() && !is_archive() ) {
        $args = array(
            'role'          => 'administrator',
            'orderby'       => 'post_count',
            'order'         => 'ASC',
            'count_total'   => false
        );

        $Admins = get_users($args); // Array of WP_User objects.
        $admin_ids = array();
        foreach ( $Admins as $post_author ) {
            $admin_ids[] = $post_author->ID;
        }

        $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
        $args2 = array('author__in' => $admin_ids, 'posts_per_page' => 12, 'paged' => $paged);

        $loop = new WP_Query($args2);

        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

                echo get_the_ID(), '<br />';
            endwhile; // end while
        }  else {
            echo "no posts";
        }
    }
}
```

I've made some corrections, first of all

- You didn't declare the `$paged` variable.
- `$admins_ids` should be an `array()` if you're going to use it for `author__in`
- I've also changed the `WP_query` variable from `$posts` to `$loop`

Comment: Can you explain why it loops infinitely and what specifically stopped it doing so? I would avoid answering in a way that gives a copy paste solution, as the asker doesn't learn anything that way and can run into the same problem again almost immediately

Comment: don't forget the `wp_reset_postdata()` at the end of the function

Comment: even with the  corrections same result :(